# Is it better to add just one column to the table instead of doing a join operation?

Tags: database, database-design

Assume we have two tables that obey normalization rules:

```
CommentTable : cID , userID , cContent , cDate . 
UserTable :  userID , uName, uBirth .... etc.
```

Here, inner join will be on userID and the goal is only to get uName which is missing CommentTable. I know that join operation are expensive. So should  add uName ? or obey normalization ?

Note : I didn't find any similar question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not denormalize. At the very least, do not denormalize yet.

Generally, you want to start your database design fully normalized. Claims that "joins are expensive" are greatly exaggerated, because modern RDBMS engines are pretty efficient about joining.

Next step is to profile and define indexes as needed. Usually, this is where your optimization ends, because proper indexing should get performance to where you need it to be.

In rare situations when you must squeeze the last drop of performance from that RDBMS you may go for normalization. But it should be done with understanding that denormalized data is a maintenance liability, and only when profiling indicates that denormalization is the only way to achieve acceptable performace.